# python CSV module- Only getting one cell filled

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I am currently studying python at school and have been playing around with BeautifulSoup and it has been pretty straight forward.  I am now trying to export a list using the csv module for python but it is not functioning the way I want it to.  Here is my code:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint
import sys

url = 'http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=restaurants&geo_location_terms=Charleston%2C%20SC'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "info"}) #this isolates the big chunks of data which houses our child tags
for item in g_data: #iterates through big chunks    
    try:
        eateryName = (item.contents[0].find_all("a", {"class": "business-name"})[0].text)
    except:
        pass

    print(eateryName)
with open('csvnametest.csv', "w") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow([eateryName])
```

I am getting all of the restaurant names(as evidence by the print function) but when I open up the Excel document it just has the last name on the list instead of all the names.  I've tried to append the eateryName but then it puts all of the names in one cell.enter code here

Comment: When you work with csv in Python, I would suggest you to use `pandas`. It will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
with open('csvnametest.csv', "w") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for row in eateryName:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are trying to write out the entire list into the CSV. You should do the following instead:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint
import sys

url = 'http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=restaurants&geo_location_terms=Charleston%2C%20SC'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "info"}) #this isolates the big chunks of data which houses our child tags
for item in g_data: #iterates through big chunks    
    try:
        eateryName = (item.contents[0].find_all("a", {"class": "business-name"})[0].text)
    except:
        pass

    print(eateryName)
    with open('csvnametest.csv', "wa") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow([eateryName])
```

The reason is that your write is outside the loop so you only write the last entry, and your write only has "w" which only writes over and doesnt append.